# Want Remove blank lines Ace Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, editor, ace-editor

Want to Bind an Html(contains white spaces in it) into Ace editor. I want to bind so that no blank lines should appear in Ace Editor.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, given your text is contained in `<pre id='text'></pre>`:

```
var el = $("#text");
el.text( el.text().split("\n").map($.trim).filter(function(line) { return line != "" }).join("\n") );
var editor = ace.edit("text");
```

It splits the string into an array by line separator, then call $.trim on each line and filters-out the empty lines, and finally join the array of lines back into a string.